# Entity Framework: Requerying source before Saving Changes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework

Right. My database table contains thousands of records and I'm reading only a few dozen by applying a date filter using EF. Say my user changes a few of them in the UI and then changes the date range from the UI to bring in some more records. The date filter controls are directly bound to two properties of my VM called DateFrom and DateTo. These properties in turn do this:

```
AllOrders = context.Orders.Where(Function(x) x.Date >= DateFrom AndAlso x.Date <= DateTo).ToList()
```

AllOrders is the property to which my UI's DataContext is bound. My question is, does this requerying throw away my local changes? Should I call SaveChanges() before requerying? What if I want to save things only when user explicitly presses the Save button?

Comment: When downvoting, one should be considerate to add a comment highlighting what's wrong with the question so I could take care of those things in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on ObjectContext you can use [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx) to tell EF what to do with the entities. If you are on DbContext I believe you can use [.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj556203). In any case you should consider using short-lived context as opposed to long-lived context.

Comment: With short-lived context how do people manage change tracking? My VM exposes properties of the Model types directly (instead of creating another layer of BO types that are carbon-copies of the Model types), so I was thinking it would be best to keep a one-context-per-window kind of approach. If I disconnect my context after loading, how do I keep track of new and changed objects?

Comment: If you have the entities but did not change them you can attach them back to the context (Attach). If you change an entity you can attach it and mark as modified. Obviously you need to find a balance - try short lived contexts and if it does not work for you (again you keep attaching and marking as modified or you don't even know if it was modified and would have to implement tracking of this) then use the context in the way it works best for you.